# How to get the Site last modified date and last accessed date in Sharpeoint 2007 webservice

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007, web-services

I am generating a site details report. I am getting major details but not able to get few details like **last modified, last accessed, Author (Creator), Created Date** through web service.

There access only to the Web service, not allowed to login to server to run Powershell of server side code.

Please let me know which methods and from which web service to access for getting above details.

Comment: Please provide more details, share code snippet. no body can answer your question with this limited information.

Comment: Actually rest code working fine, need information about method or code in web service will give those values.

Answer (score -1):

[SPWeb](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.aspx) Class

This class represents a SharePoint site. It will contain a collection of information for a single SharePoint site.

The following are the public properties are used from SPWeb class to display the SharePoint Site details.

Ref: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/article.php/c19515/Retrieving-SharePoint-Site-Information-in-an-ASPNET-Web-Application.htm

[image]

Comment: hi i need method or code from webservice. i cant run  server end code, client does not allow it